# Python: Sum of all permutations of outer products of numpy arrays of arrays

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-ndarray, numpy-einsum

I have a numpy array of arrays Ai and I want each outer product (np.outer(Ai[i],Ai[j])) to be summed with a scaling multiplier to produce H.  I can step through and make them then tensordot them with a matrix of scaling factors.  I think things could be significantly simplified, but haven't figured out a general/efficient way to do this for ND.  How can Arr2D and H more easily be produced?  Note: Arr2D could be 64 2D arrays rather than 8x8 2D arrays.

```
Ai = np.random.random((8,101))
Arr2D = np.zeros((Ai.shape[0], Ai.shape[0], Ai.shape[1], Ai.shape[1]))
Arr2D[:,:,:,:] = np.asarray([ np.outer(Ai[i], Ai[j]) for i in range(Ai.shape[0]) 
    for j in range(Ai.shape[0]) ]).reshape(Ai.shape[0],Ai.shape[0],Ai[0].size,Ai[0].size)
arr = np.random.random( (Ai.shape[0] * Ai.shape[0]) )
arr2D = arr.reshape(Ai.shape[0], Ai.shape[0])
H = np.tensordot(Arr2D, arr2D, axes=([0,1],[0,1]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good setup to leverage `einsum`!

```
np.einsum('ij,kl,ik->jl',Ai,Ai,arr2D,optimize=True)
```

Timings -

```
In [71]: # Setup inputs
    ...: Ai = np.random.random((8,101))
    ...: arr = np.random.random( (Ai.shape[0] * Ai.shape[0]) )
    ...: arr2D = arr.reshape(Ai.shape[0], Ai.shape[0])

In [74]: %%timeit # Original soln
    ...: Arr2D = np.zeros((Ai.shape[0], Ai.shape[0], Ai.shape[1], Ai.shape[1]))
    ...: Arr2D[:,:,:,:] = np.asarray([ np.outer(Ai[i], Ai[j]) for i in range(Ai.shape[0]) 
    ...:     for j in range(Ai.shape[0]) ]).reshape(Ai.shape[0],Ai.shape[0],Ai[0].size,Ai[0].size)
    ...: H = np.tensordot(Arr2D, arr2D, axes=([0,1],[0,1]))
100 loops, best of 3: 4.5 ms per loop

In [75]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,kl,ik->jl',Ai,Ai,arr2D,optimize=True)
10000 loops, best of 3: 146 µs per loop
```

**`30x+`** speedup there!